# ReactJS: Deep nested state

Tags: reactjs, nested, state

Let's say I have this React component:

```
    class SomeComponent extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          topObject: {
            childObject1: {
              grandChildObj1: {
                attr1: this.props.val1,
                attr2: this.props.val2
              }
            },
            childProp: 1
          },
          topProp: 2
        };
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <span>{this.state.topObject.childObject.grandChildObject.attr1}
            </span>
          </div>
          // ...
        )
      }

      changeDeepNestedStateValue(val) {
        // need code here to change the state
        // set topObj.childObject.grandChildObject.attr1
        // to the 'val' argument
      }
    }
```

What code would I need inside the function 'changeDeepNestedStateValue' so that it changes the state immutably so that React detects the change and re-renders?

Are deep-nested state values a bad practice or anti-pattern?  If so, is there an optimal structure to a state, a flat one maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Deep nesting is not necessarily an anti-pattern but just makes your code harder to maintain and reason about. In order to trigger a re-render and update component state, all you have to do in the `changeDeepNestedStateValue` function is call `this.setState({ topObject: {...} })` with whatever new state you want to update. Optionally, `this.setState` also takes a function that exposes the previous state of the component as seen below.

```
this.setState((prevState) => {
  if (prevState.topProp === val) {
    doSomething();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend having a look at immer

https://github.com/mweststrate/immer

It provides a super easy way to work with nested objects in terms of immutablilty

But yes, flatter state with out of the box react state management is better practice

Comment: great, thanks for the lead on Immer.  I bookmarked it.